# Create record in ExtJs 6 vs Previous Versions

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5, extjs6

I have noticed that the result when creating a record is different in ExtJs 6 comparing to older versions.

I have run the following in the console using chrome. I define the following model.

```
 Ext.define('mymodel',{
   extend :'Ext.data.Model',
   fields : [
     {name:'firstname'}
  ]
});
```

Then I create a record using this model.

```
 var rec = Ext.create(mymodel,{
     firstname: 'Peter',   
     lastname: 'Venkman'
 });
```

When I get the data from this record

```
rec.getData();
```

the result is

**ExtJs 6**

```
Object {firstname: "Peter", lastname: "Venkman", id: "mymodel-1"}
```

**ExtJs 4**

```
Object {firstname: "Peter", id: undefined}
```

In ExtJs 6

```
lastname
```

is being created although it is not defined in the model. Anyone know why is this? Something changed that I can't find in the docs.

Comment: Just for clarification: it's been this way since ExtJS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's covered in the [`What’s New in Ext JS 5`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/whats_new/whats_new500.html):

> The Model constructor no longer extracts fields from the data object
>   it is given but rather adopts it and upgrades it based on the
>   converters and default values from your defined fields. This means
>   that you no longer need to define every field you want to keep on your
>   record. As long as the server sends the data in the desired format,
>   those properties will remain on the record’s data object. These
>   undeclared fields are assumed to be persistent, so changes will be
>   tracked and included in saves back to the server.

Comment: Basically, the problem is not with the id. I did not mention that. I am wondering why in extjs6 `lastname` is being created since it is not defined in the model